# Site visualization problem with Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-browser, webpage-rendering

I have a site based on Solar Sentinel Joomla template. [www.sism.org](http://www.sism.org)

I'm having some visualization problem with chrome.

The right side-bar is shifted down after all the content, while it should be floating on the right!

Could someone explain me why?

PS: the template css is pretty messy, and there is some custom css and js made by me inline at the beginning of the page.

EDITED

Comment: Without an example/code, we can't really do anything.

Comment: of course i forgot to put the link...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer your question because you've not provided any code or other way for us to determine what might be going on for you.

At a guess, I'm going to say that the main content div on your page is extending (in width) and forcing the sidebar to drop underneath.

You can test this by making your main content section slimmer and see if the right hand bar decides to shift back into place.

As for why this might only be happening in Chrome and not other browsers, it's hard to know without more information.